# Mongoid: Creating many objects with a single call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have 1000 users that i will be retrieving from Twitter, and I would like to save them at one shot, as opposed to doing 1000 insertions individually.

How can I do this on Mongoid? Something like this would rock:

```
TwitterUser.createMany([{:name=>u1}, {:name=>u2},{:name=>u3}] )
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you have to do this "in one shot" ?

Comment: it is a user facing feature. the user would be waiting while i do this ;)  I tink i can cache enough data to make the twitter part work fast enough

Comment: For anyone coming here and thinking this will make things quicker or even atomic - [check the code for yourself](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb#L140) - it's *not* using insert_many - it just calls itself with each item and saves each item individually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the Mongo ruby driver to do this. You can pass an array of hashes to the [`insert` method](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.0.8/Mongo/Collection.html#insert-instance_method) to create multiple documents at once (more info on this [google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_frm/thread/4c4152c7b49213fd/5ace861635ad2e91?#5ace861635ad2e91)). Mongoid makes it easy to access the ruby driver.

The code would look something like this:

```
user_list = twitter_accounts.map do |account|
  # create a hash of all the fields to be stored in each document
  { 'name' => account.name, 
    'username' => account.username 
    # some other fields...
  }
end

Mongoid.master['twitter_users'].insert(user_list)
```

Comment: this answers it well. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. The Mongo ruby driver is very cool and Mongoid makes it very easy to access it. Don't be afraid to use the ruby driver and raw MongoDB queries.

Comment: yes, trying to get to that level of competency. as with any new tech, needs quite a bit of handholding at the start

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it, it's `create`, not `createMany`. You can use it like this:

```rb
TwitterUser.create([
  { username: "u1", display_name: "Display Name 1" },
  { username: "u2", display_name: "Display Name 2" },
  { username: "u3", display_name: "Display Name 3" }
])
```

Also, as [@bowsersenior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385405/1533054) points out, it's a good idea to use it with [`Array#Map`](https://www.omniref.com/?q=Array%23map):

```rb
TwitterUser.create(
    @users_array.map do |u|
        { username: u.username, display_name: u.name }
    end
)
```

---

From the [`Mongoid#Persistence`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html) Docs:

> [***Model.create***](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard)
>
> Insert a document or multiple documents into the database
>
> [***Model.create!***](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard)
>
> Insert a document or multiple documents into the database, raising an error if a validation error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MongoidModel.create directly.